# C# Open XML and get value

Tags: c#, xml

I am opening a XML file and need to get a specific value from it. I read to recordingowner then I want to get its value.

This is what I've come up with so far where n is path to an xml file

```
public void ReadXMLFile(string n)
{

    if (Path.GetExtension(n) == ".xml")
    {

        // XML File found
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.Load(n);
        string xmlcontents = doc.InnerXml;

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlcontents)))
        {

            reader.ReadToFollowing("recordingowner");
            string t = reader.Value;

            Console.WriteLine(t);

        }

    }

}
```

However t does not contain anything. This is the XML file

```
<recording>
<dataformat>audio</dataformat>
<starttime>2014-03-19 11:52:42:000 +0100</starttime>
<endtime>2014-03-19 11:58:15:000 +0100</endtime>
<nostart>false</nostart>
<noend>false</noend>
<recordingtype>stnbulk</recordingtype>
<recordingline/>
<servicename>1000</servicename>
<servicenumber/>
<deliberatebreak>0</deliberatebreak>
<calldirection>Incoming</calldirection>
<filename>66633769853.wav</filename>
<otherinum>0</otherinum>
<callparty>1</callparty>
<recordingowners>
<recordingowner>411111111</recordingowner>
</recordingowners>
<parties>
<party id="1">
<number>0000</number>
<pstarttime>2014-03-19 11:58:15:982 +0100</pstarttime>
<pendtime>2014-03-19 11:58:15:982 +0100</pendtime>
</recording>
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: I'd look into Linq-to-Xml (`XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument`) because it's a little easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Two things

1) Your provided XML is invalid as its missing couple end tags for parties and party

2) Use following to replace string t = reader.Value; with 
string t = reader.ReadElementString();

```
        // XML File found
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(val);

        string xmlcontents = doc.InnerXml;

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlcontents)))
        {

            reader.ReadToFollowing("recordingowner");
            string t = reader.ReadElementString();

            Console.WriteLine(t);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
```

fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do this (but it does need to be valid XML)

```
var t = XDocument.Load(n)
    .Element("recording")
    .Elements("recordingowners")
    .First()
    .Element("recordingowner")
    .Value
```